# Finding correct sign for a square root in a differentiable equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2LHl.jpg) problem, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}y$, $y(6)=-4$ where the solution $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{2x^2+C}$, $C=-56$, is shown, however I don't understand how the correct sign $y(x)=-\sqrt{2x^2-56}$ is found for the square root. square rooting both sides causes the right side to be plus or minus, and I need to find which one is correct.

Comment: When you substitute in the initial condition, you have that $-4$ equals plus or minus the square root of some quantity. In order for both quantities to be equal, they must also have the same sign. Since -4 is negative, the right-hand side must also be negative. The square root of a real quantity is always non-negative (assuming we want to avoid imaginary numbers). Thus, we need the negative sign in front so that the sign of both sides of the equation are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the sign for the square root in this case you have to consider what the sign of $y$ is at $6$.  It is negative so your expression on the right must also be negative so you can't use the principle square root because that's always positive so solution is $y = -\sqrt{2x^2 - 56}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of finding y and then putting x=6 and y=-4 is not a right method. You have to direct put values in equation you obtain after integrating.

We have,

8 = 36 + c

c = -24